# how to change an attribute of an svg file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this has been answered before but no solutions are working for me. I want to render an svg file on an html page and access its code elements from javascript. I want to change the attributes of specific elements. Specifically I want to change add an attribute style="fill:#FFFFFF;". Later I will want to remove this. I want to access the element with the id property of the element. I tried doing this with a plethora of javascript code and rendering the svg as an img and an object and nothing works. Is this possible? If so how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use `D3.js`?

Comment: Are you going to do it in reactjs or vanilla?

Comment: this is a react app. I thought it'd be easier to get the answer with vanilla.

Comment: Dunno what D3 is. ill look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a react component for your SVG and control their properties with props in **react** way:

```
const SampleIcon = ({fill='red',backgroundColor='white', width='300', height='200'}) => (
  <svg version="1.1"
     width={width} height={height}
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill={backgroundColor} />
    <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill={fill}>SVG</text>
  </svg>
)
```

Now use it:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <SampleIcon fill='green' backgroundColor='#ff0'/>
    <SampleIcon with={400} height={300}/>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I had trouble loading my svg. It was generated with photoshop and had extra tags that was breaking my react app. I put the svg code into this website to help me create a react component for it.: https://react-svgr.com/playground/

Comment: Yes, some tags on SVG may be in conflict with the react, unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this concept but as a solution, I do the same as you with the mentioned website to create my react component. Thanks for your useful information @Dan

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the fill property of an SVG you want to display in an img tag. However, you can change the `filter` property.

So what you want to do is display the svg file like so:

`<img class="svg-icon" src="./your.svg"/>`

You **have to** give your img tag a classname (also, do not set the fill property inline).

Then you can simply apply a `filter` and the color of the svg will be changed, like so:

```
.your-icon {
  filter: invert(14%) sepia(95%) saturate(6069%) hue-rotate(360deg) brightness(108%) contrast(117%);
}
```

The above filter is red. Use this hex to filter converter to find the right color for you: [hex to filter](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp).

Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-haibt-sqvg2?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: That is not my use case. This fiddle has the code embedded in the html. i want to read the svg file from a file and display it in an img or object tag. I want to access the elements from there. The above code does not work for this use case.

Comment: Ok. So if I want to change the color of an element of the svg then I have to actually have the full code for the svg in the react code like other answers here? If I read the svg from file and display in an img/object tag then I can only change the entire svg color not its individual elements?

Comment: Thanks. this was a good answer but ultimately I really need to change the elements on the svg so I see I need to actually embed the svg code in the react component.